# Implement interface on class as part of a Code Fix

Tags: c#, interface, roslyn

As part of a Roslyn code fix, I need to implement an interface on a class, if the class does not already implement it.

So far I'm able to detect whether the class implements the interface:

```
var implements = false;
foreach (var b in t.BaseList.Types)
{
    var name = (b.Type as IdentifierNameSyntax)?.Identifier.ValueText;
    if (name == "IInterfaceName")
    {
        implements = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, if `implements` is false, I need to add the interface to the list of basetypes.
I've tried `t.BaseTypes.Add(...)` and here I'm a bit stuck - not sure how to construct the right parameter.

Is this the right approach?

Comment: You could write that as `bool implements = t.BaseList.Types.Select(b => b.Type).OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>().Any(t => t.Identifier.ValueText == "IInterfaceName");` using Linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking if a class declaration implements an interface or not could be done in a more elegant way through checking the underlying symbol's `AllInterfaces` property.

```
c.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(((ClassDeclarationSyntax)c.Node)).AllInterfaces
```

In your code fix, then you could use the `SyntaxFactory` to construct your new tree, and then modify the document to contain the newly constructed tree. Note that in Roslyn most of the things are immutable, so if you just start calling `Add(...)`, it will return a new instance of your object but not change the one which is in the document.

As for the modifications with the `SyntaxFactory`, you can always refer to the [RoslynQuoter](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/).

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding a solution. First, it was necessary to use the semantic model rather than the syntax tree to determine whether the interface is already implemented - there may be multiple partial classes for the declaring type; in such a case the syntax tree only describes one partial class.

The code looks like this:

```
var result = document.Project.Solution;

var m = start.Parent.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().First(); // the method to add
var t = start.Parent.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().First(); // the class type

var semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync(cancellationToken);
var typeSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(t, cancellationToken);

var i = typeSymbol.Interfaces; // the interfaces in the semantic model. Includes declared interfaces on all partial classes.

// does the type implement the interface?
var implements = false;
foreach (var b in i)
{
    if (b.Name == "IInterfaceName")
    {
        implements = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!implements)
{
    var newClass = t.AddBaseListTypes(SyntaxFactory.SimpleBaseType(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("IInterfaceName")));

    // get root for current document and replace statement with new version
    var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
    var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(t, newClass);

    // return new solution
    result = document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot).Project.Solution;
}

return result;
```